# Symfony "Welcome page" seems incomplete

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu

I *thought* I have Symfony all up and running ok on the VM machine I've been trying to set up. However after following the instructions on this link:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup

I'm not getting reassuring 'welcome' page in the screenshot. Instead, I just see an empty page with 'Homepage.' written in the corner. The underlying HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Welcome!</title>
                <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
            Homepage.

<div id="sfwdtc2fded" class="sf-toolbar" style="display: none"></div>
<script>

/* [editor's note: the JS code of the toolbar has been removed] */

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get exactly the same whether I go to: `http://localhost/app.php` or `http://localhost/app_dev.php`

Does anyone know what could be causing this? The link `http://localhost:8000/config.php` works perfectly and I have no errors there (just one recommendation to install INTL extension but I don't suppose that's the problem).

Comment: Please, please don't tell me that you have coded the second code box with this formatting?!

Comment: @Rizier123 that's code automatically injected by Symfony when debug toolbar is enabled

Comment: @Bendy Do you have AcmeDemoBundle in your "src" directory? You probably said "NO" when installer asked you whether you want it installed. If you did then that's it, everything works, you just didn't install demo bundle.

Comment: Thanks @IgorPantović, I doubled checked in the directory you gave and I do have the AcmeDemoBundle there though - I remember installing it as I want to go through the demo to get a feel for how I a site all fits together in Symfony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably installed Symfony 2.6, which had an AppBundle delivering your this page. You can comment the line registering the AppBundle in `app/AppKernel.php` to see the demo homepage.

Comment: Thanks @WouterJ, I've opened `app/AppKernel.php` and tried commenting out whole `$bundles` array and the whole `if(` statement... as well as each component of each individually. Most of them gave a new error when I tried to load the page (a couple sent me to the same page just saying 'Welcome' as before?

Comment: @Bendy only comment out the line with `new AppBundle\AppBundle(),`. Symfony relies on bundles to work, not registering them would lead to very big errors :)

Comment: thanks @WouterJ for getting back to me. I tried commenting out this line (luck more than judgement!) but it still gives an error: `FileLoaderLoadException in Loader.php line 73: Cannot load resource "@AppBundle/Controller/". Make sure the "AppBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class.`. Should I perhaps give a fresh install of Symfony? I haven't modified anything since installing (other than LAMP server, webroot and setting permissions)

Comment: Ah,  no. Since you now did not register the appbubdle, sf can't find its routes.

Comment: Please note that there is nothing wrong qith your install and you can just continue following the docs

Comment: Thanks once again - reassuring to know the installation itself is OK - although I'm completely new to frameworks and MVC so am hoping to get Acme demo working so I can look around and try to pick up tips. I guess I can't use Acme as my install stands. At what point should I have registered the app Bundle? I can do a new install :)

Comment: Ypu peobably can use the demo bundle, juat not thr homepage as it's overridden by the appbundle (this is going to be fixed). Just go to /demo and see the nice demos

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by running

```
composer require symfony/framework-bundle
```

and it seems to have solved me problem.